# SQL query gets stuck if adding ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I am working with a query, which looks like this

```
SELECT s.c1, s.t, s.u, s.dt, t.temp, t.dt AS dt2
FROM `systemusage` AS s
    INNER JOIN temperature AS t ON s.did=t.did
WHERE t.did = (SELECT id FROM devices WHERE m = 1)
LIMIT 1
```

Which works just fine, however if I add `ORDER BY s.id`, then the query gets totally stuck, can someone guide me on why? the id field is primary, so it should be indexed no?

Comment: Do you have an index on `temperature.did`?

Comment: Is there only one row in `devices` with `m=1`?

Comment: I'm guessing that the downvotes are for not including the output of `EXPLAIN`. That's how you diagnose performance problems in SQL.

Comment: There was no indes on t.did, but there is now. And yes, ther is atm only one device with `m=1`, but that could change in the future.

Comment: If that could change, you should use `IN`, not `=`. You can only use `=` when the subquery returns exactly one row.

Comment: I think the index on `t.did` should help. It uses that to find the matching rows before it orders by `s.id`.

Comment: Okay, thank you very  much, I've added the index and will change the query to use `IN` instead.

Comment: it did the trick to add index on `t.did`, should have checked that at first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an index on the column `temperature.did` so that the `WHERE` clause can be implemented efficiently.

It also may help to replace `WHERE t.did = (SELECT ...)` with a `JOIN`.

```
SELECT s.c1, s.t, s.u, t.temp 
FROM `systemusage` AS s 
INNER JOIN temperature AS t ON s.did=t.did 
INNER JOIN devices AS d ON d.id = t.did
WHERE d.m = 1
ORDER BY s.id DESC, t.id DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I don't know if you got a bit of spare time to maybe guide me a bit further, it did help creating the index on `t.did`, but not for long sadly, as soon as there is coming more rows the query begins to take over a minute again. I tried the `EXPLAIN`, which gave me this: https://i.gyazo.com/f9da8a9e1cd48668493ce8887e3f7ff9.png
I though of sth like combine index between tables, but couldn't find anything useful. I'm kinda stuck at what to try next.

Comment: Can you create a sqlfiddle with the full table definitions and sample data?

Comment: Couldn't get sqlfiddle to work, but used this instead: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/escQEbwFmMsh9c3BsxX7uz/1

Comment: You seem to have all the necessary indexes. I've updated the answer to show how to do it with a `JOIN`.

Comment: Very nice, I'm still reading up about all the join functions, so much to read :) So far the query goes very very fast, like all others, but there ain't many rows right now, will try to run it again later when a few thousand rows has been added, thank you so very much so far!

Comment: Update, it's the same, there is now about 8k rows in each table (only 10 in device table), the query takes about 10 seconds.. Can it simply be because the database is based on an Raspbbery Pi, even tho there is no overload, but it's still an SD Card. I would think if it's because of the SD Card, then there should be many more slow queries.

Comment: Is there enough memory to hold the indexes? You may want to go to [dba.se] to ask questions about optimizing database performance on small devices like RPi.

Comment: I don't think this is something you can solve with the query syntax -- this is about as simple as the query can get.

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate your help so far, helped me a great way.